# Ionic FabricJs Problem with access to function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, fabricjs

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.loadCanvas();
}
loadCanvas(){
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
        this.canvasMouseDown(e);    
    });
}
canvasMouseDown(e){
    console.log(this.lock);
    console.log(this.pausePanning);
    if(!this.lock){
        this.pausePanning = true;
    }
}
```

That is code. Every time when I click I get error. Like below

[Ionic error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx1Pq.png)

I tried every combination and still have this same problem

Comment: `loadCanvas(){
    let self = this;
    canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
        self.canvasMouseDown(e);    
    });
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabric events are [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to an object which triggers them, which means that here:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
    this.canvasMouseDown(e);    
});
```

`this` is an instance of `canvas`. And when you're calling `this.canvasMouseDown()`, you're essentially calling `canvas.canvasMouseDown()`, so this is where the error comes from. Try using the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as the event handler:

```
loadCanvas(){
    canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
        this.canvasMouseDown(e);    
    });
}
```